# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.security.providers.SecurityVendor_j2se

Tags: spring, noclassdeffounderror, tibco, ems

I have a web-app trying to connect to a secured TIBCO EMS using Spring. At startup, when the MessageListener tries to startup, am getting the following even though tibjms.jar and tibcrypt.jar are present in the WEB-INF\lib direcetory. The app is deployed in JBoss 7.

15:44:14,814 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed:
[...]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.security.providers.SecurityVendor_j2se
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.tibco.security.impl.ooOO.init(SecurityVendor.java:128) [tibcrypt.jar:]

If I expand the tibcrypt.jar file, I can clearly see the class 'com.tibco.security.providers.SecurityVendor_j2se' present.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I don't know why this worked but am glad it did. I followed the following:
[Configuring EMS over SSL on JBoss](https://docs.tibco.com/pub//collaborative_information_manager/8.3.0_march_2013/doc/html/tib_cim_8.3.0_installation/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=tib_mdm_Configuring_Java_Messaging_Server.07.8.htm&single=true)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by path issues. When the jar files are loaded. 
So in our case we solved it by adding  this line on the `.tra` file in order for the 
`TIBCrypt.jar` to be loaded first.

```
tibco.env.CUSTOM_EXT_PREPEND_CP=%TRA_HOME%/lib/TIBCrypt.jar
```