# JBoss EAP 6.4 migration to tibco SSL Queues with jms 1.1 library

Tags: jboss, java-ee-6, jboss6.x, tibco, tibco-ems

I want to migrate our current tcp Queues to SSL Queues in JBoss EAP 6.4.23 on java 8 jdk1.8

It's a legacy application and i've got the tibjms 7.0.1.4 library and JBoss provided jms 1.1 in place.

Now, after all the SSL configuration I receive the following error:

```java
.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.security.TIBCOSecurity
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService$1.run(ComponentStartService.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_211]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tibco.security.TIBCOSecurity
```

I've read that I need to add some stuff to the classpath, but either I'm doing it wrong or I'm not sure where to put it.

Also another option would be to upgrade to tibjms 8.4.1 but then I receive and error like java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext

Thank you so much in advance and best regards

Comment: Looks like you need TIBCrypt.jar in classpath,. please also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458763/noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-com-tibco-security-providers-se

Comment: Hey @DavidAbragimov thank you.
Could you tell me how to add this to JBoss classpath?
The current module.xml for /genericjms/provider/main looks like:
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.jboss.genericjms.provider">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="tibcrypt.jar"/>
    <resource-root path="tibjms.jar"/>
 
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.jms.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>